# Matcher's appendReplacement method ignores the replacement's backslashes

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `s` and a regex. I would like to replace each match of the regex in `s` with a replacement string. The replacement string might contain one or more backslashes. To perform the replacement, I'm using `Matcher`'s [appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

The problem with `appendReplacement` is that it ignores all the backlashes it encounters in the replacement string. So if I try replacing the substring `"match"` in the string `"one match"` with the replacement string `"a\\b"`, then `appendReplacement` results in `"one ab"` instead of `"one a\\b"`*:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("match").matcher("one match");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
matcher.find();
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "a\\b");
System.out.println(sb); // one ab
```

I have taken a look at `appendReplacement`'s code, and found out that it skips any encountered backslash:

```
if (nextChar == '\\') {
    cursor++
    nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
    ...
}
```

How can I replace each match with a replacement string that contains backslashes?

(*) - Note that there's a single backslash in `"a\\b"`, not two. The backslash is just escaped.

Comment: `"a"+"\"+"b"` ????????

Comment: @vks: If you're asking whether my example replacement string is `"a"+"\"+"b"`, then yes, except that `"\"` is an illegal Java string because you have to escape the backslash.

Comment: I was actually asking if that replace ment works :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **double escape** the backslash i.e.:

```
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "a\\\\b");
```

**Full Code:**

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("match").matcher("one match");
sb = new StringBuffer();
matcher.find();
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "a\\\\b");
System.out.println(sb); //-> one a/b
```

Reason being that Java allows you to use backreferences like `$1`, `$2` etc in replacement string and that enforces same escaping mechanism for backslash as in the main regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement` if the replacement string should be treated literally. It escapes all `\` characters and also `$` characters.

```
String replacement= "a\\b" 
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape escapes

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("match").matcher("one match");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
matcher.find();
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "a\\\\b");
System.out.println(sb);
```

Alternatively use [replace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm)

```
String test="one match";
test=test.replace("match", "a\\b");
System.out.println(test);
```

**output :**

```
one a\b
```

Comment: Just fyi, original answer only had `replace` code but now `matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "a\\\\b");` has also appeared after my answer